# Find element in qi::symbols

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have a struct like this one :

```
struct SNumbers: qi::symbols<char, signed>
{
   SNumbers()
   {
      add
         ("One", eOne)    
         ("Two", eTwo)
         ("Three", eThree)
         ("Four", eFour)
         ("Five", eFive)
    ;
   }
} Numbers;
```

I want to find/iterate to access char field by enum type.
Can you help me ? I tried to use `find()` and `for_each()`, but I failed.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099202/searching-iterating-boostspiritqisymbols) may help.